# Working with numbers in Python

Tags: python, csv, numbers, decimal

**Hello. I am very new to Python and programming in general.**

***I have 3 columns from CSV file***

```
X,CH1,CH2,  
Second,Volt,Volt,  
2.66400e-02,4.00e-03,1.04e-03,  
-2.66360e-02,4.00e-03,7.20e-04,  
-2.66320e-02,4.00e-03,5.60e-04,  
-2.66280e-02,4.00e-03,3.20e-04,  
-2.66240e-02,4.00e-03,8.00e-05,  
-2.66200e-02,4.00e-03,-2.40e-04,  
-2.66160e-02,4.00e-03,-5.60e-04,    
-2.66120e-02,4.00e-03,-7.20e-04,  
-2.66080e-02,4.00e-03,-1.04e-03,   ***for example.***
```

***I am using*** 
:

```
with open('maximum.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for _ in xrange(2):
       next(f)
```

***to skip first two lines, as this is just text, and then***

```
for row in reader:
  x=(float(row[2]))
  print(x)
```

***gives me***

```
0.00104  
0.00072  
0.00056  
0.00032  
8e-05  
-0.00024  
-0.00056  
-0.00072  
-0.00104
```

**So there is the question:**

***What should I write, so that it will give me an integer number instead of decimals, like***

```
104  
72  
56  
24  
8  
24  
56  
72  
104
```

***P.S I do not want just to multiply by 10^5***

Thanks

Comment: *Why* don’t you want to multiply? This is the easiest and the most appropriate way to do this.

Comment: Your units is volts, you want to change units. Most strait forward thing is to multiple.  I myself would probably multiple by `1e6` so that I'm dealing with microvolts, but if you want it in 10s of mircrovolts thats fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to multiply by 10 ^ 5 because you actually want to have bigger number.

Then apply function int() and get 104 instead of 104.0